# How do I define Mongo connection in NodeJS app when deploying it on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am trying to deploy my first app to heroku using mLab MongoDB addon. How should I define the connection?

This is what I found in a NodeJS book, it does not seem to work, though. I replaced the password and database name with appropriate values.

```js
mongoose.connect('mongodb://databasename:password@kahana.mongohq.com:10089/app26');
mongoose.connection.on('open', function() {
    console.log('Mongoose connected.');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Heroku enviroment variables. When you add a Mongo addon you should automatically have the enviroment variable available (these can also be accessed through the Heroku dashboard). So with MLAB you can get your connection string by accessing process.env.MONGOLAB_URI. So you can just do `mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI);`

To get this to work on your localost you run `heroku config > .env` to export the enviroment variables to a .env file at the root of your app. Then when you run `heroku local` the MONGOLAB_URI env variable will be also available on your localhost.